# Date format toUTCString in Lua

Tags: date, lua, utc, luajit

I have a question regarding date formatting in **Lua (Luajit)**. I need to get UTC string, for example, like I would do it in JavaScript:

```
var date = new Date()
console.log(date.toUTCString()) // "Fri, 06 Dec 2013 14:05:28 GMT"
```

Unfortunately in Lua I cannot find possibility to format date this way:

```
print(os.date()) -- Fri Dec  6 16:06:43 2013
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*From the [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.date):*

> If format starts with '`!`', then the date is formatted in Coordinated Universal Time. [...]
>
> If format is not "`*t`", then date returns the date as a string, formatted according to the same rules as the ANSI C function `strftime`.

Based on this and a little [documentation referencing](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime), it's quite simple to construct a format string that resembles JavaScript's `toUTCString` format.

```lua
> =os.date('!%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
Fri, 06 Dec 2013 14:27:34 GMT
```